# What happened to the android duplicates of the SG-1 team?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the episode "Tin Man," the SG-1 team is:

> duplicated as androids, and eventually decide to stay behind and repair the broken down facility.

Later, in the episode "Double Jeopardy," they:

> appear on the world Juna and help the "real" SG-1 team, while also sacrificing themselves (the robotic team).

Is there any mention of what happened to Harlan, the old facility, and how the team got to Juna?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After "Double Jeopardy", there's no mention of Harlan again, so (as far as I'm aware), there's no canonical answer as to his fate.  stargate.wikia.com, gateworld.net, and StargateWiki don't mention anything after the events of "Double Jeopardy".

> [However](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Harlan#Theories), in "Tin Man", he was able to re-create Robo-Teal'c after the first one malfunctioned, so it's possible that he simply created new versions of SG1 after the originals were destroyed in "Double Jeopardy".

Comment: I was under the impression that was why they were still there, so now that they're not, he can't.  _Awkward attempt at avoiding nullifying the spoilerisms_